# C Passing Struct To Function

Tags: c, function, struct

I'm trying to pass a struct with predefined data to a function, so I don't have to use multiple functions for multiple structs, but so I just can use 1 function for multiple structs.

The structs look like this:

```
typedef struct {
    char* vehicleName;
    char* previewDir;
    char* previewName;
} vehicleSpawner;

vehicleSpawner vehicleSport[] = {{"adder","lgm_default","adder"},{"autarch","",""},{"banshee2","lsc_jan2016","banshee2"},{"bullet","lgm_default","bullet"}};
vehicleSpawner vehicleSportTwo[] = {{"adder","lgm_default","adder"},{"autarch","",""},{"banshee2","lsc_jan2016","banshee2"},{"bullet","lgm_default","bullet"}};
vehicleSpawner vehicleSportThree[] = {{"adder","lgm_default","adder"},{"autarch","",""},{"banshee2","lsc_jan2016","banshee2"},{"bullet","lgm_default","bullet"}};
```

Right now to display the info in the structs I have to use use 3 separate functions, like the one below.

```
void vehicleSport() {
    menu.title("Sport");

    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        char* name = UI::_GET_LABEL_TEXT(vehicleSport[i].vehicleName);
        Hash key = GAMEPLAY::GET_HASH_KEY(vehicleSport[i].vehicleName);

        if(!GAMEPLAY::ARE_STRINGS_EQUAL(name, "NULL")) menu.option(name).vehicleSpawn(key).vehiclePreview(vehicleSport[i].previewDir, vehicleSport[i].previewName);
    }
}

void vehicleSport2() {
    menu.title("Sport Two");

    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        char* name = UI::_GET_LABEL_TEXT(vehicleSportTwo[i].vehicleName);
        Hash key = GAMEPLAY::GET_HASH_KEY(vehicleSportTwo[i].vehicleName);

        if(!GAMEPLAY::ARE_STRINGS_EQUAL(name, "NULL")) menu.option(name).vehicleSpawn(key).vehiclePreview(vehicleSportTwo[i].previewDir, vehicleSportTwo[i].previewName);
    }
}

void vehicleSport3() {
    menu.title("Sport Three");

    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        char* name = UI::_GET_LABEL_TEXT(vehicleSportThree[i].vehicleName);
        Hash key = GAMEPLAY::GET_HASH_KEY(vehicleSportThree[i].vehicleName);

        if(!GAMEPLAY::ARE_STRINGS_EQUAL(name, "NULL")) menu.option(name).vehicleSpawn(key).vehiclePreview(vehicleSportThree[i].previewDir, vehicleSportThree[i].previewName);
    }
}
```

---

**What I want to achieve** is being able to use just *one function* instead of a function for the amount of structs I have, and repeating the same function everytime.

**What I've tried** is passing it using a different function, and from there accessing it in the "dynamic function" like so:

```
char* vehicleSpawnerTitle;
struct structurename;

void vehicleSpawnerItemMenu() {
    menu.banner(vehicleSpawnerTitle);

  for (int i = 0; i < sizeof(structurename)/sizeof(structurename[0]); i++) {
        Hash key = GAMEPLAY::GET_HASH_KEY(structurename[i].vehicleName);
        char* name = UI::_GET_LABEL_TEXT(VEHICLE::GET_DISPLAY_NAME_FROM_VEHICLE_MODEL(key));

        if(STREAMING::IS_MODEL_VALID(key) && STREAMING::IS_MODEL_A_VEHICLE(key) && !GAMEPLAY::ARE_STRINGS_EQUAL(name, "NULL"))  menu.option(name).vehicleSpawn(key).vehiclePreview(structurename[i].previewDir, structurename[i].previewName);
  }
}

void setVehicleSpawnerVar(char* title, struct structname) {
    vehicleSpawnerTitle = title;
    structurename = structname;
}
```

Hopefully someone can assist me on this!

Comment: `char* vehicleName = "adder"` is invalid, missing `const`.

Comment: Off-topic:  Use `std::string` instead of character arrays.   Arrays can overflow and you need to pass the capacity and size of arrays to functions.

Comment: You seem to be programming in C, not C++.

Comment: If your function requires multiple instances of the same struct, use `std::vector` and pass by reference.  The `vector` maintains the size (quantity of elements).

Comment: How about something like: `void vehicleSpawnerItemMenu(const std::vector<vehicleSpawner>&)` ?

Comment: If you are using C++, then a class hierarchy will solve your problem rather elegant. But it seem that you are actually programming in C, right?

Comment: Off-topic:  You don't need `typedef struct` in C++.  The `struct` is a unique type.

Comment: @StephanLechner Yes that is correct, a solution in C would be best in my case (but since the code contains a small portion of C++ I figured I had to use the C++ tag instead)

Comment: Retagged question   as C

Comment: I was not aware of that C allowed an identifier like `UI::_GET_LABEL_TEXT`  - sure you don't program C++ ?

Comment: That's likely because C *does not* allow such identifiers, @MichaelBeer, as I suppose is your point.  The code presented is neither valid C nor valid C++.  It's closer to the latter, but written in a style more characteristic of the former.

Comment: Furthermore, I only see 1 single struct, `vehicleSpawner` and three arrays containing several of these structs. I don't see the need for three different functions in here at all, one single function like `vehicleSpawnerMotorcyclesMenu(struct vehicleSpawner *spawners, size_t number_of_spawners_in_array)` should do pretty well. What's the problem?

Comment: @MichaelBeer This code was put together to demonstrate the problem I'm having and the result I'm trying to achieve. Yes, I have over 10 structs with lots of data. Pasting 10+ functions on here with the same purpose like the one in the question is probably not appreciated.

Comment: Then could you show at least 2 different ones?

Comment: @MichaelBeer I have edited the question and included 2 more functions.

Comment: Slight remark: If I understand what you want to do here correctly: `void setVehicleSpawnerVar(char* title, struct structname) {
    vehicleSpawnerTitle = title;
    structurename = structname; }` Ive got to disappoint you - C/C++ does not offer meta-programming facilities like Java or other languages - your `structname` / `structurename` are typenames, not variables to contain types of structures. In C or C++ there are no variables that you could assign types to. `struct structname` does NOT declare a variable `structname` to contain a type of struct, but a type *forward* declaration...

Comment: There is still only one struct type, `vehicleSpawner`, and 3 arrays of this struct... However, you can join the three functions `vehicleSport`, `vehicleSport2` etc. If that's what you are looking for.

Comment: @MichaelBeer Hmm I see, haven't thought about joining them. That would basically utilize a single (big) struct, if I'm correct, like so `{{{"bfinjection","",""},{"bifta","",""}},{{"bfinjection","",""},{"bifta","",""}}}`?

Comment: I just set up an answer to give you a piece of sample code to join the 3 functions to be used with all 3 arrays of yours...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you attempt you want to unite the 3 functions `vehicleSport`, `vehicleSport2`
 and `vehicleSport3`, you should be able to achieve this by:

```
void vehicleSport(vehicleSpawner *spawner, size_t number_of_spawners_in_array) {
    menu.title("Sport >>>I ommitted the number here, you can add it if you wish easily<<<");

    for (size_t i = 0; i < number_of_spawners_in_array; i++) {
        char* name = UI::_GET_LABEL_TEXT(spawner[i].vehicleName);
        Hash key = GAMEPLAY::GET_HASH_KEY(spanwer[i].vehicleName);

        if(!GAMEPLAY::ARE_STRINGS_EQUAL(name, "NULL")) menu.option(name).vehicleSpawn(key).vehiclePreview(spawner[i].previewDir, spawner[i].previewName);
    }
}
```

And call the function like

```
vehicleSport(vehicleSport, 4);
vehicleSport(vehicleSportTwo, 4);
vehicleSport(vehicleSportThree, 4);
```

Or, if you dread the hard-coded sizes for the arrays, call it like:

```
vehicleSport(vehicleSport, sizeof(vehicleSport) / sizeof(vehicleSport[0]);
```

Also, you could just omit the length entirely and hard - code it into the function if all three arrays will always have the same size. But I would avoid that and always hand over the length explicitly.

But be aware that, since the initial example does not compile, the code above might contain typing errors - You will have to add the appropriate header inclusion directives on your own. Moreover, as you requested, this is a *C solution* - but your code is clearly C++.

Hope this answers your question, although I fear that even if it does, I might have to explain a little further about why the arrays appear as pointers in the function and you can index them nevertheless?

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for! Thank you